# Choose best function name in repository

Tags: clean-code, readability, naming-standards

In my code, I'm using repository pattern. For example, I got deal repository. I just curious how you decide the name of the function when the function itself doing so many things. I think when the function name too long it can decrease code readability. Is this considered bad because of function name too long in terms of clean code.

For example below is the list of the function I wrote in DealRepository Class:

- GetAllDealsWithinValidRangeStartDateEndDateUserLimitAndQuota
- GetAllDealsForCategoryWithinValidRangeStartDateEndDateUserLimitAndQuota
- GetUniqueSubCategoriesForDealsWithinValidRangeStartDateEndDateUserLimitSubCategoryAndQuota
- GetAllDealsForSubCategoryWithinValidRangeStartDateEndDateUserLimitAndQuota

The function name too long because when you want to retrieve deal, got many things to filter like deal within 10KM radius, deal start date, deal end date, deal quota, deal quota per user and others. Any suggestion or opinion how to choose a good name for this function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature of the method is not only its name, but also the return type, the arguments, the generic parameters, etc. In your case, it looks like the names, for most part, repeat what is already specified by the arguments.

If your programming language supports overloading, you can end up with something like this:

- `DealRepository.GetAll(DateRange range, int userLimit, int quota)`
- `DealRepository.GetAll(Category category, DateRange range, User user, int quota)`
- `DealRepository.GetAll(SubCategory sub, DateRange range, User user, int quota)`
- `DealRepository.GetSubCategories(DateRange range, User user, int quota)`

By forcing the caller to specify the range, you show that the values you yield return will be within the range (otherwise, the method wouldn't make any sense.) The same goes for the user limit and the quota.

If your language has optional parameters too, you can reduce even more the number of methods:

- `DealRepository.GetAll(DateRange range, int userLimit, int quota, Category category: null)`
- `DealRepository.GetAll(SubCategory sub, DateRange range, int userLimit, int quota)`
- `DealRepository.GetSubCategories(DateRange range, int userLimit, int quota)`

and then, by making `Category` and `SubCategory` inherit from the same *abstract* class `Grouping`, you can refactor that to:

- `DealRepository.GetAll(DateRange range, int userLimit, int quota, Grouping grouping: null)`
- `DealRepository.GetSubCategories(DateRange range, int userLimit, int quota)`

### What happened with `Unique`?

By using the principle of least astonishment, you may indeed, like in my example below, omit `Unique` from the name. In other words:

- If the user expects, by calling `GetSubCategories`, to receive only distinct values, don't add `Unique` to the method name.
- If the user would assume that the method could yield duplicate values, then `GetUniqueSubCategories` is preferable to show that the values are necessarily unique. Or you may change the signature of the method to return a type which corresponds to a sequence containing only distinct values.

### Does `GetSubCategories` really belong here?

If `GetAll` return a typed sequence (such as `DealsCollection`), you may move `GetSubCategories` to this class. Instead of doing:

```
new DealRepository().GetSubCategories(...)
```

the caller will rather do:

```
new DealRepository().GetAll(...).GetSubCategories()
```

### A few remarks...

Aside the fact that `WithinValidRangeStartDateEndDateUserLimitAndQuota` has no place in the name of the method, there are a few issues as well:

- `WithinValidRange`: why not simply `WithinRange`? Would it make sense for a caller to query for deals within an *invalid range*?
- `StartDateEndDate`: you shouldn't do that even at object level. It's not `Date start, Date end`. It's a date range. So create a `DateRange` class.
- `All` feels wrong. Currently, the caller doesn't retrieve *all the deals*, but only the deals which correspond to the specified filters.
- Depending on the community using the language, it may be acceptable to remove `Get` prefix, leading to `DealRepository.All(...)` and `DealsCollection.SubCategories()`.
- If you are able to use the iterator pattern, then the method becomes:

  ```
  DealRepository.GetAll()
  ```

  without arguments. It is used this way:

  ```
  DealRepository
      .GetAll()
      .Where(d => range.Contains(d.date) && d.user == user)
      .Take(quota)
  ```

Comment: In this case, the programming language I used is Go language which does not support method overloading and optional parameter. Anyway, I got the idea like you tell if the programming language support method overloading and optional parameter. Got any other idea for the programming language not support method overloading?

Comment: @zer0fl4g: What about polymorphism? In other words, you'll have one method which has one argument of interface or abstract class type. And then you'll have different classes for different needs: one will use the grouping, another one wouldn't, etc. I don't know Go, so I can't be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

It may be a good idea to have a single method that accepts an object as the parameter instead, if the queries are sufficiently configurable.  This is called the [Introduce Parameter Object](http://refactoring.com/catalog/introduceParameterObject.html) refactoring.

```
public class GetDealsParameter
{
    public DateTime? Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime? End { get; set; }
    public int? Limit { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}

public class DealRepository 
{
    public IEnumerable<Deal> GetDeals(GetDealsParameter dealsParam)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

In this example you would only set the values you would like to filter on.

If you need help constructing the parameters object you could also use the [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).